# Why is ajax waiting for over a second?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having a bi of an issue. When I make an ajax request, it goes through fine, but the status is waiting for just over 1 second. That just seems really high to me.

Here is a screenshot of the network tab in chrome
[image: Network tab]

Here is the ajax function I am using.

```
function subCommentSubmit() {
        $('.subComment').on('submit', function() {

            var url = "/laravel/public/utility/submitsubcomment"; // the script where you handle the form input.
            // Submits the data with ajax, method type is POST
            var currentElement = $(this);
            var thatPar = currentElement.parent().parent();
            var liveSubCommSection = $('> .live-sub-comments', thatPar);
            var commentLoader = $('> .loader-comments > .loader', thatPar);

            var formData = currentElement.serialize();
            $('.new-reply', currentElement).val('').blur().trigger('autosize.resize');

            commentLoader.removeClass('hide').fadeIn(250, function() {
                $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: url,
                       data: formData, // serializes the form's elements.
                       success: function(data)
                       {    
                            commentLoader.fadeOut(250, function() {
                                commentLoader.addClass('hide');
                                var response = JSON.parse(data);   
                                var commentPost = $('<li class="single-user-reply"> <div class="user-ava-cont"> <a href="'+ response.userid +'" class="user-ava-a"><img src="../images/avatest1.png"> </a> </div><div class="s-w-user-details"><a href="'+ response.userid +'" class="s-w-poster upop">'+ response.username +' </a> <span class="s-w-timestamp">1 second ago</span><a href="#" class="likes-but notliked active">Like</a> <a href="#" class="likes-but liked">Liked</a><ul class="more-dropdown-cont" role="button"> <li class="dropdown minidrop"><button class="more-dropdown dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon down"></i></button><ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="people"><li role="presentation"><a class="u-a-a" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Block User</a></li><li role="presentation"><a class="u-a-a" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Report Abuse</a></li></ul></li></ul><div class="s-w-user-post">'+ response.comment +'</div><div class="clear"></div></div></li>');
                                commentPost.hide();
                                liveSubCommSection.append(commentPost.fadeIn(250)); 
                                subCommentSubmit();
                            });
                       }
                }); 
            });
            currentElement.unbind('submit');
            // Ensures it doesn't route the form the normal way, and ajax takes over
            return false;

        });
    }
```

Comment: ajax doesn't "wait" on its own. it'll react as the server sends data. The real question to ask is 'why is laravel taking over a second to process the request'.

Comment: Does it take a second for the server to process and handle the request?  What you're looking at is the network requests/responses, not any profiling of the JavaScript code execution.  AJAX is waiting because the server hasn't replied.

Comment: Is this a consistent issue?  It might just be a slow day for connections.  It also could be whatever the server's doing.

Comment: Waiting time is dependent upon how much time is taken by server to respond you. So its related to your server side coding

Comment: Can You explain Your php file ?

Comment: Post php code and we can see if it can be sped up.

Answer (score 1):

I would profile your PHP file because that seems to be the source of your issue.

I am not familiar with Laravel's profiling options but something simple you can do is this:

```
class utility{

    function submitsubcomment(){
        $start = microtime(true);

        //Your code is here

        echo (microtime(true) - $start);
    }

}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. Forget AJAX for a moment. Just create a HTML form and with the action being the `/laravel/public/utility/submitsubcomment`, method being POST and the form fields as before. This will demonstrate that AJAX is not at fault.
2. Use this form to work out why the server is taking so long. Get the PHP to log times between steps and then this will discover where things are taking the time. You can speed up this process by creating a harness that sets the appropriate environment variables and then run it from the command line.

If you are using a database make sure you have the appropriate indexes for the queries.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that my database was incredibly slow. The code itself was perfectly fine. I was connecting to my local DB using localhost, which is much slower than using 127.0.0.1. Once I changed the DB host, it fixed my issue!